# Facing issue while migrating Hibernate from 3.3.2.GA to 3.6.10.Final

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, migration

I am facing the below issue when i replace 3.3.2.ga to 3.6.10.final. I have removed the hibernate annotations from POM. since it is moved to hibernate-core.

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean 
property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource
[/WEB-INF/dao-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: STRING
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of dao-config.xml

Comment: I cant expose my code as per company policies.  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name 'domainDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dao-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dao-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: STRING

Comment: and we upgraded the spring 2.5.6 to 2.5.6 sec

Comment: Wrong combination of jars and please post the full stack trace instead of a snippet.

Comment: Also you still need the `hibernate-annotations` not everything moved to core...